# Visual Studio window with several tabs - howto make tab icons visible?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, window, icons

Is there any way to make windows tab icons always visible? When window is not pinned, or big enough to display text, it looks like this:
[image]

Icons appears only when we make this window too small to fit text on tabs:
[image]

Is there any registry hack or something to make those icons always visible?